# Truncate cell value with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a table that has 100% width. It is generated dynamically with values from my db. I need to truncate `TH` values if they do not fit in the table, without pushing the boundaries of the cell. If the value is truncated I'd like to add a link with **...** and put the full length label into title tag. I don't need it to expand. Something like this:

```
<th>
   Long label<a href="javascript:void(0)" title="$myFullValue">...</a>
</th>
```

I'm not sure how to get the value of the string...

```
$("TH").width();
$("TH").val().width(); ??
```

I know there are some jQuery plugins out there but I was not able to find what I need and I thought I could try and give this project my own whirl.

http://jsfiddle.net/b3cQZ/3/

---

EDIT:

Just an idea that crossed my mind. Couldn't I wrap the label in  tags and get it's width. At the same time get the width of the parent TH. If labe's width is greater, I could

1. subtract, say 20 px (for ...) from TH width and,
2. assign that width to span's width
3. while adding **overflow:hidden**, and
4. appending "..." to the span

Won't this work?

Comment: santa... please in future try to prepare at least a [JSfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) or a [JSbin](http://jsbin.com)

Comment: @roXon this is not always neccessary.

Comment: The table in the demo is not 100% wide...

Comment: @Šime Vidas I just wanted to make if short enough for the long label to push.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution uses a fixed value but if you're able to find a way to calculate the `maxLength` you could wrap this in a `function` and pass it the output as the `maxLength`.

**FIDDLE** http://jsfiddle.net/m72Ja/2/

**HTML**

```
<table class="MyTable" border="1" width="400">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Col 1</th>
            <th>Col 2</th>
            <th>Long Long Long Col 3</th>
            <th>Col 4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.MyTable th').each(function() {
        var maxLength = 10;
        //if the value is greater than max length,      
        //cut the string to max length then add ...     
        if ($(this).text().length > maxLength) {
            $(this).text($(this).text().substring(0, maxLength));
            $(this).append($("<a href='javascript:void(0);' title='$myFullValue'>...</a>"));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The table has a 100% width (not in the OP's fiddle, but in the question itself), and the issue is that the number of characters that will be displayable is not known.

Comment: Yeah I see that now, @Tomalak.  That's why I edited this answer sometime ago to describe that it required a fixed length.  At this point, it just shows how you would go about truncating the value and appending the `<a>...`

Answer (score 1):

`$("TH").width();` Is meant to grab the actual width dimension of the element not the length of the text. For that just use the traditional js "length" attribute: `$("TH").text().length;` Overall what you are tring to do is good and not all that hard to do on your own. I usually have the server side set up the links and the text I need to truncate as it already knows about the length and everything but if you are rendering on client side its fine to do it there. Wrap what you want to hide in a "span" element with a css class like "none" `.none{display:none;}` on it that way all you need to have the handler do is add or remove class as appropriate.

Comment: How can you do it on the server-side? You don't know how wide the containing element will be.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simplistic example based strictly on the number of characters in the cell. Wouldn't be necessary if there was long line of text with spaces because text would most likely wrap.

```
$("TH").each(function(){//loop over cells
  var that = $(this);//placeholder for cell
   if(that.html().length > [some value]){//test length of html
     var span = $("<span />");//create span
     span.html(that.html().substring(0, [some value]));//set html of span
     span.attr("title", that.html());//add title
     that.empty();//empty cell
     that.append(span);//add span to cell
  }
});
```

Comment: Is [some value] a width in a number of characters or width in px?

Comment: @santa- @tomalak [some value] would just be a placeholder for the maximum character length you want to allow in a cell. Thanks at @roX0n!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `th`'s width will be expanded until you do the truncation, and you can't do the truncation until you know the width that you want the `th` to be.

I suggest giving the `th` the style `overflow: hidden` so that it doesn't expand. Then put the text inside a `<span>` (or possibly a `div`).

You may then be able to use `$('th').width()` and compare with the width of your text `div`. How you go about determining an appropriate place to truncate the string:

- (if you use a monospaced font) is now really easy
- (if you use a variable-width font) may require iteratively chopping off characters until the `div` fits in the `th`. Yeugh!

Comment: Meh, tables tend to expand and stuff on their own. I'm not really sure that this approach will work now.

Answer (score 0):

There's a jQuery Plugin to accomplish your task.

http://devongovett.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/text-overflow-ellipsis-for-firefox-via-jquery/

Comment: Yes, I've seen a few making use of CSS3 features. The problem with it is that it's not yet officially released, and therefore does not have to be supported by browsers. Thanks for the link.